# Send various data types from android to php using android volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have an android app. I want to send POST request to a php file. The parameters consist of arrayList and Strings. I want to do something like this:

```
private Map<String, String> params;

    public RequestPostBook(long id, ArrayList<String> bookNames, ArrayList<String> bookAuthors, ArrayList<String> subjects,
                           String date,Response.Listener<String> listener)
    {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);


        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("candidateId", id + "");
        params.put("bookName",bookNames);
        params.put("authorName",bookAuthors);
        params.put("subjectName",subjects);
        params.put("reqDate",date);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
```

This is giving errors as the Map is (String, String).. Please help me about how to get it done. Please rectify this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params is a `Map<String, String>`, so it can only take String as values.
You are trying to put `ArrayList`s into it.
What you might want to try is

```
JSONArray bookNamesJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(bookNames));
JSONArray bookAuthorsJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(bookAuthors));
JSONArray subjectsJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(subjects));
```

and then pass these objects to params

```
params.put("bookName",bookNamesJSON.toString());
params.put("authorName",bookAuthorsJSON.toString());
params.put("subjectName",subjectsJSON.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I apply this solution then can I use something like this in php:      $bookNames[]=$_POST["bookName"];

Comment: You have to decode the JSON like this: $bookNames = json_decode($_POST["bookName"]);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Map` is composed of `<String,String>` and you are passing an `ArrayList<String>`. You should do something like `bookNames.toString()` then you'll send a `String`

Or also you can create a `JSONArray` as follows :

```
JSONArray types=new JSONArray(Arrays.asList.(bookNames));
```

And then do the `types.toString()` and should work.

Then to decode it with PHP you should use `json_decode` function

```
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I apply this solution then can I use something like this in php: $bookNames[]=$_POST["bookName"];

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee that's another question, you can accept this one that it's for Android side and then create another for PHP, then you can link me the question and I'll try to answer better.

Comment: Here is the link to the other question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056910/loop-through-values-of-a-jsonarray-in-php

Comment: ok, but you have to accept first this one, I'll take a look in some hours.

Comment: I am sorry but I will have to mark Giorgio's answer as correct. I know that both of your answers say the same thing but his answer is a bit more well formed and easily understandable. No hard feelings, I hope.

Comment: It's okay, don't worry :)