# Loop through values of a JSONArray in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I have 3 arrayLists in android app. I am sending them to php via android volley POST request like:

```
public RequestPostBook(long id, ArrayList<String> bookNames, ArrayList<String> bookAuthors, ArrayList<String> subjects,
                           String date,Response.Listener<String> listener)
    {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);

        JSONArray bookNamesJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(bookNames));
        JSONArray bookAuthorsJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(bookAuthors));
        JSONArray subjectsJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(subjects));


        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("candidateId", id + "");
        params.put("bookName",bookNamesJSON.toString());
        params.put("authorName",bookAuthorsJSON.toString());
        params.put("subjectName",subjectsJSON.toString());
        params.put("reqDate",date);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
```

Now I have to use the values in the arrayList in php to execute a series of similar queries. I am trying this in php:

```
$candidateId=$_POST["candidateId"];
$reqDate=$_POST["reqDate"];
$subjectName=json_decode($_POST["subjectName"]);
$bookName=json_decode($_POST["bookName"]);
$authorName=json_decode($_POST["authorName"]);
$i=0;
foreach($subjectName as $value)
{
    $subject=$subjectName[$i];
    $book=$bookName[$i];
    $author=$authorName[$i];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO BookRequisition VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);");

    $stmt->bind_param("dssss", $candidateId, $subject, $book, $author, $reqDate);

    $stmt->execute();

    $i++;
}
```

When I run this through the app, this is what I am getting in my BookRequisition table:

```
12100116050(candidateId)    Array(subjectName)    Array(bookName)    Array(authorName)    2019-03-08(reqDate)
```

Can anyone please help me on how to send the correct values to the table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell what output you get when do `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @Saji am very new to php. Can you please tell me where should I put this?

Comment: Just put before the `foreach($subjectName as $value)`

Comment: @ArnabBanerjee, write the following at the very top of your code snippet above, run the code, and please share the results with us: `var_dump($_POST);exit;` This will help us understand how the data you're getting looks like, and how it should be treated. Your task is relatively straightforward once the data format is understood.

Comment: @Saji  output:   array(5){
["reqDate"]=>
string(10) "2019-03-08"
["authorName"]=>
string(17) "[["theo","Yash"]]"
["candidateId"]=>
string(11) "12100116050"
["bookName"]=>
string(20) "[["css","let us C"]]"
["subjectName"]=>
string(13) "[["web","C"]]"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
<?php

$candidateId = $_POST["candidateId"];
$reqDate = $_POST["reqDate"];
$subjectName = json_decode($_POST["subjectName"])[0];
$bookName = json_decode($_POST["bookName"])[0];
$authorName = json_decode($_POST["authorName"])[0];

foreach ($subjectName as $i => $subject) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO BookRequisition VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("dssss", $candidateId, $subject, $bookName[$i], $authorName[$i], $reqDate);
    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

Note: You should do the proper validation on the data posted from your device.

Comment: I have to insert multiple books in the BookRequisition table. The lists contain the details of those books. So, I thought that the $stmt should be  executed multiple times using different values from the lists. This solution will insert only one book. Am I wrong?

Comment: Great answer. Thankyou so much